# NetBeans' Code Assistance works wrong with Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt, netbeans, autocomplete

It's surprising that I can't find already answered questions about it.
This screenshot speaks better than words:

[image: Imgur]

I can build and run program without errors. But in NetBeans I have

> "There are unresolved includes"

and

> "Unable to resolve identifier"

errors. What is interesting, is that there are several completions for Qt namespace (GlobalColor, AltModifier), but other aren't found by NetBeans' code assistance.

Comment: BTW, you are programming in the C++ language, not C.  The C language doesn't have the `iostream` header file.  Please edit your tags accordingly.  Also, verify that your compiler is using the C++ language.

Comment: Please review your Netbeans settings to verify that you are using the C++ language and the appropriate C++ compiler (like `g++` not gcc).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I edited my tags. Yes, I'm using right g++ compiler. NetBeans setups it automatically when creating QtApplication project.

Comment: Check this old Bug [code completion for C++ and Qt does not work under Windows](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=132136)

Comment: @MohammadKanan How can a bug in an older release of NetBeans that was closed over eleven years ago with status "VERIFIED FIXED" possibly be relevant?

Comment: @skomisa I don't understand too. Especially, user on this page wrote that all works properly on Linux. I'm using Arch Linux and NetBeans 8.2. I have "/usr/include" in Code Assistance include directories. Even if I provide full path to Qt includes ("/usr/include/qt") problem isn't solved. And also I use g++ and not MinGW. I tried reinstall qt5-base and qt5-doc packages, create new projects. Nothing can solve this problem.

Comment: Actually this open (i.e. unresolved) NetBeans bug looks more like your problem: Bug [271324 - build doesn't fix "Hello Qt World" project](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=271324)

Comment: @skomisa Thank you! Right Click on Project -> Code Assistance -> Reparse Project really help with unresolved includes. But problem with Qt namespace didn't  go. I also tried to "Clean C/C++ cache and restart IDE". Nothing.

Comment: @skomisa I found exactly my problem. But it's very old bug (2013) and it's marked as fixed. Anyway: [Bug 231938 - Qt5: unresolved identifiers in "C/C++ Qt Application" projects](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231938)

Comment: @skomisa, oops , there was a recommended work around `soldatov 2008-04-05 20:00`  that I thought OP might give a try!

Comment: @MohammadKanan I tried recommended workaround but it helps only with "Unresolved includes" problem but not with "Unresolved identifier" with QtCore namespace.

Comment: @Elnee, yes I noted.